# mutating method sent to immutable object error when using mutable array functions

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist, nsmutabledictionary

My application always popping 'mutating method sent to immutable object'
My dictionary and the array already declare to be a mutable one but seems it doesn't help
I have tried the replaceObjectAtIndex function it also didn't work.

```
NSString* plistpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistpath];
NSMutableArray* Array1 = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Array1"];
[Array1 removeObjectAtIndex:num];
[Array1 insertObject:@"1" atIndex:num];
return Array1;
```

thanks

Comment: How did did you add `Array1` to `dictionary` and how did you create it before adding it?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Array1"]; // Immutable
NSMutableArray * Array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array]; // Mutable
// ...
```

Or as Julien noted:

```
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Array1"]; // Immutable
NSMutableArray * Array1 = [array mutableCopy]; // Mutable
```

Comment: you can also use mutableCopy method (e.g.: [[dictionary objectForKey:@"Array1"] mutableCopy];)

Answer (score 0):

If the right hand side does not return an NSMutableArray (NSArray instead) you try to mutate an in mutable object.

> > NSMutableArray* Array1 = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Array1"]; // NSArray